# One point union, second homotopy group is not finitely generated?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, spheres

Let $X$ be the one-point (*wedge sum*) union of the circle $S^1$ and the sphere $S^2$. What is the easiest way to see that the abelian group $\pi_2(X)$ is not finitely generated?

Answer (score 6):

Recall that $\pi_n(X) \cong \pi_n(\widetilde{X})$ for $n > 1$, where $\widetilde{X}$ is the universal cover of $X$.

That said, universal cover of $X = S^1 \vee S^2$ is $\Bbb Z$-many $S^2$'s wedged at $\Bbb R$. From the previous remark, $\pi_2(X) \cong \pi_2(\tilde{X})$. As $\tilde{X}$ is simply connected, Hurewicz's theorem implies $\pi_2(\tilde{X}) \cong H_2(\tilde{X}) \cong \bigoplus^\infty \Bbb Z$ which is not finitely generated.

Comment: And note that the $\pi_1X$ action via Deck groups gives also $H_2\bar X \cong \mathbb Z[\pi_1X]\cong \mathbb Z[t^{\pm 1}]$ is a free module over the group ring .

Answer (score 0):

Instead of going via covering spaces, as is traditional, you can also use a  Higher Homotopy Seifert-van Kampen theorems (HHSvKT), as in this book [Nonabelian Algebraic Topology](http://pages.bangor.ac.uk/~mas010/nonab-a-t.html) (pdf available there).  The Introduction to Chapter 8 explains  that if $X=S^n \vee [0,1], n>1,$ then $\pi_n(X, \{0,1\})$ is the  free module on $1$ generator over the groupoid $\mathcal I= \pi_1([0,1],\{0,1\})$. When you identify $0,1$ in $X$ you get $S^n \vee S^1$ and the groupoid $\mathcal I$ becomes the group $\mathbb Z$.  The HHvKT implies what you want.

I agree that the background and proof of the HHSvKT is complicated, but it does easily  give so much more, such as a generalisation of the Relative Hurewicz Theorem, and nonabelian results in dimension $2$ on second relative homotopy groups. Students should also know about modules over groupoids!